# Как в GO принять данные отправленные фронтендом?

Tags: golang, backend

Есть сайт который отправляет данные на сервер POST. Как заставить GO принять эти данные и вывести их в консоль.
Вот код фронтенда :

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    class PersonInput extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            my:[]
        };
      }
         getData = () => {
          return axios(`http://localhost:8000/post`, {
            method: "post", withCredentials: true, data: {
              first_name: 'Fred' ,      //вот эти данные бэкенд должен вывести  в консоле бэкенда
              last_name: 'Flintstone'      //вот эти данные бэкенд должен вывести в консоле бэкенда
            }
          }).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            console.log(res.data)
        })
        }
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
           <form >
               <input type="text" name="name" />
               <button onClick={this.getData()} >Click!!!</button>
           </form>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export default PersonInput;
```

Вот код бэкенда :

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
     "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
type Response struct {
  Status string `json:"status"`
}
func postName(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){  //функция для запроса POST
    fmt.Println("God")
}
func getName(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request) {
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Response{Status: "OK"})
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/get",getName).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/post",postName).Methods("POST")
    fmt.Println("Listen and Server")
    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"})
    originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8081", "http://localhost:3000"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "OPTIONS", "DELETE"})
    credentialsOk := handlers.AllowCredentials()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000" , handlers.CORS(headersOk, originsOk, methodsOk, credentialsOk)(router)))
}
```

То есть бэкенд должен записать данные из фронтенда в переменную и вывести их в консоле. Помогите пожалуйста с кодом два дня мучаюсь никак не могу вникнуть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func postName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Если "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        log.Print("ParseForm(): ", err)
        return
    }
    log.Print(r.PostForm.Get("first_name"))

    // Если "Content-Type: application/json"
    var d struct {
        First_name string `json:"first_name"`
        Last_name  string `json:"last_name"`
    }
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&d)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("NewDecoder(): ",err)
        return
    }
    log.Print(d.First_name)
}
```